# Two layered modal went behind the dark background

Tags: asp.net, bootstrap-modal

[image]

What could have caused this. It works fine when it only display 1 layer of modal and this happens when there are two layers of them and then the whole page became disabled.

Comment: I can think of 2 cases. One may be you are experiencing a javascript error and rest of the code did not run. The other you have some zindex issue with your model dialog!

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `UseSubmitBehavior="false"`, `data-dismiss="modal"` attributes to your button.

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" 
    Text="Button" UseSubmitBehavior="false" data-dismiss="modal" />
```